# http Request.FormFile : handle zip files?

Tags: go

I'm writing a web server in go.

On one of the pages, the user can upload a file.

I would like to be able to handle zip files.

In the `archive/zip` package, I only see two functions which allow me to read from a zip archive :

1. `func OpenReader(name string) (*ReadCloser, error)`
2. `func NewReader(r io.ReaderAt, size int64) (*Reader, error)`

I would like to avoid writing and reading back from the disk,
if I want to use the second function, I need to know the size of the uploaded file before calling the function.

**Question**

I will split my question in two parts :

1. What would be the idiomatic way to read the unzipped content of a zip file uploaded through a standard `multipart/form-data` html form ?
2. How can I get the actual size of a file uploaded through a html form ?

   ```
   func(req *http.Request) {
       f, h, err := req.FormFile("fileTag")
       if err != nil {
            panic(err)
       }
       var fileSize int = ??

       unzipper, err := zip.NewReader(f, fileSize)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way I found to get the size :

```
func(req *http.Request) {
    f, h, err := req.FormFile("fileTag")
    if err != nil {
         panic(err)
    }
    fileSize, err := f.Seek(0, 2) //2 = from end
    if err != nil {
         panic(err)
    }
    _, err = f.Seek(0, 0)
    if err != nil {
         panic(err)
    }

    unzipper, err := zip.NewReader(f, fileSize)
}
```

I don't find this solution very elegant or idiomatic.

Isn't there some cleaner way to handle this case ?

Comment: does the mime-header solution from my answer not work? If you're missing a content-length, this solution is actually very good, since I don't think there's a way to get it into a Buffer without at least one more copy.

Answer (score 3):

You can look for the file size in the FormFile's [Header](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#FileHeader) (which is a [MIMEHEader](http://golang.org/pkg/net/textproto/#MIMEHeader)).

```
h.Header.Get("Content-Length")
```

If there is no content length for the file, you can read it into a buffer first to get the size.

```
var buff bytes.Buffer
fileSize, err := buff.ReadFrom(f)
```

Other options are to seek to the end, as you put in your answer, or get the concrete Reader out of the interface. A multipart File will be an `*io.SectionReader` if it's in memory, or an `*os.File` if it was written to a temp file:

```
switch f := f.(type) {
case *io.SectionReader:
    fileSize = r.Size()
case *os.File:
    if s, err := f.Stat(); err == nil {
        fileSize = s.Size()
    }
}
```

Comment: No `Content-Length` in the headers ... However, `Content-Length` would be the value of the header written by the client, right ?

Comment: yes, it's a header in the multipart form (*not* the http request headers), so it would have to be sent by the client.

Comment: Thanks for the SectionReader suggestion. Unfortunately, f may either be a SectionReader, or a os.File. See [the code for FileHeader.Open](http://golang.org/src/pkg/mime/multipart/formdata.go?s=2942:2984#L121)

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot that this could be put into a tempfile transparently. You could do a type switch for os.File too, but I'd say the Seek solution is actually the cleanest overall, since it covers all bases at once.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an in-memory buffer and make sure to limit the max upload size of a file (~100MB?)
Here it is using `io.Copy`

```
import (
    "archive/zip"
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func HttHandler(req *http.Request) {

    f, _, err := req.FormFile("fileTag")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    fileSize, err := io.Copy(buf, f)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    zip.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes()), fileSize)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take size from the header:

```
file, header, err := r.FormFile("zipfile")
// do something with error
zipReader, err := zip.NewReader(file, header.Size)
// do something with error
```